# Click an html element JS

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to make a javascript to "click" a specific element?

on my page I've got a  with a specific id, and I want to make a JS script to click the div on certain event. is there any method like:

```
document.getElementById("idofdiv").click()?
```

Comment: are you trying to trigger a click event? If yes, what you posted in the question itself would work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to trigger a click event by javascript.

```
document.getElementById('element').click();
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('#element').click();
```

Please note that the click event won't work if you are trying to force a click on an anchor tag which opens a page. There are tricks called as "clickjacking" which you can use to force it, but this way you're cheating the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
document.getElementById("idofdiv").onclick = function() {
  //your code here
}
```

or

```
document.getElementById("idofdiv").onclick = someFunction;
function someFunction() {
  //your code here
}
```

See:: [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

I guess you answered your own question.